# Updating BIOS for Linux

Tags: linux, bios

Does anyone know a reliable guide to reinstall or update BIOS from flash drive having a computer running under Linux OS?

Comment: Start with your motherboard's user manual. They usually provide BIOS ROM updates, required utilities and detailed instructions. Linux can only help you to write data to flash drive or something like that, you don't need to be an expert in Linux to do that.

Comment: Computer make/model? For example, some ASUS motherboards allow updating BIOS from within BIOS itself, from a file on a USB stick, so this is OS-agnostic.

Comment: An old Dell D620.

Comment: Just be sure to format the drive as FAT 16 or FAT32. Most BIOSes only work with them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

=> BIOS Upgrade [documentation](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/BIOS_Upgrade) from thinkwiki.

=> Another good [how-to](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic.php?p=907198) located at Gentoo forum.

=> Biosdisk simplifies the process of flashing your system BIOS under Linux on Dell desktops and laptop. For Dell servers use different rpm provided by Dell.

=> You can use FreeBIOS project for flashing using native Linux tools i.e. no .exe files

Sources: cyberciti